# python makefile can't find python command

Tags: python, makefile

On my M2 Mac, Python makefile does not work. I'm running everything in iterm2.

```
test-local:
        TREE_SITTER_LIB_PATH=./test python -m pytest
```

Error when running makefile:

```
➜ make test-local
/bin/sh: python: command not found
make: *** [test-local] Error 127
```

Python path:

```
➜ which -a python
python: aliased to /usr/local/bin/python3.9

➜ python
Python 3.9.17 (main, Jun 20 2023, 17:20:08)
[Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

My .zshrc file. I read other SOF articles so I tried adding to my path to no avail.

```
alias python=python3

PYTHON="$PATH:/Users/lewis.chi/Library/Python/3.9/bin"
PYTHON1="/usr/local/bin/python3.9"
PYTHON11="/usr/local/bin/"

export PATH=$PATH:$PYTHON:\$PYTHON1:\$PYTHON11
```

Comment: From the error `/bin/sh: python: command not found` I would assume that it's run from a bash shell and not zsh. Did you try changing the path in your .bashrc file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
➜ which -a python
python: aliased to /usr/local/bin/python3.9
```

This implies that `python` is a *shell alias*.  Shell aliases are local to the shell that you're using, they are not exported to sub-shells and `make` doesn't know anything about aliases.  So, you cannot run aliases from within make recipes.

If you want to make this work, you have to find a different way.  You can use a make variable and set it to the right value on the command line, you can use a `python` script instead of an alias, you can make `python` a symbolic link to `python3`, etc. etc.

But you cannot use a shell alias.

Ditto for shell functions, by the way: they are also local to the shell and not exported.